# Is it possible to redirect error messages to browser window in Resin 4?

Tags: resin

In case of compilation error Resin shows a simple page with the only message:

> **Server Error**
>
> The server is temporarily unavailable due to an internal error. Please
>   notify the system administrator of this problem.

And all significant information I should seek in the log file.

Is it possible to redirect somehow all error diagnostics to the browser window?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting <development-mode-error-page/> tag to true. In later versions of Resin the value is externalized into resin.properties:dev_mode

http://caucho.com/resin-4.0/reference.xtp#developmentmodeerrorpage